# Complex Number With Super ()

Tags: java, class, math, methods

I am trying to write a ComplexNumber class that inherits data and methods from my ImaginaryNumber class. So in my ImaginaryNumber class I have this

```
public class ImaginaryNumber 
{
  //Declaring a variable.
  protected double coefficient;

  //Default constructor.
  public ImaginaryNumber( )
  {
      this.coefficient = 1;
  }

  //Parameterized constructor.
  public ImaginaryNumber(double number)
  {
      this.coefficient = number;
  }

  //Adding and returing an imaginary number.
  public ImaginaryNumber add (ImaginaryNumber another)
  {
      return new ImaginaryNumber(this.coefficient + another.coefficient);
  }//More Codes
```

And in my ComplexNumber class I have this

```
public class ComplexNumber extends ImaginaryNumber
{
  private double realCoefficient;

  public ComplexNumber ( )
  {
      super ( );
      this.realCoefficient = 1;
  }

  public ComplexNumber (double realNum, double IM)
  {
      super (IM);
      this.realCoefficient = realNum;
  }

  public ComplexNumber add (ComplexNumber a, ComplexNumber b)
 {
    return new ComplexNumber (this.realCoefficient + a.realCoefficient,  super(b) + super(IM)); //I am confused on what to do here.
 }//More Codes
```

The part that I am stuck at is the addition. I don't know how to call the method from my ImaginaryNumber class to handle the Imaginary part. I assumed that I have to use super () in some form. But I don't know the correct syntax to call a method.

Also just to double check. Am I calling my constructor in my ImaginaryNumber class correctly?

Comment: @ pzaenger Thanks, didn't know it was that simple. However, now I am getting an error saying that it can't find IM, but didn't I declared IM in the parameterized constructor?

Comment: `super.add(...)`? (Added comment again for completeness).

Comment: It is because `super(IM)`. `IM` is only known within the constructor. Think about adding another variable, like `private double IM;` and in the constructor `this.IM = IM;`. (Like you did with `realCoefficient`)

Comment: @pzaenger Ok I got. I'll take it from here. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think so , by doing this you want to acheice addition of complex numbers.So for this in your ImaginaryNumber class you must have a method that returns coefficient.

```
  public double getImaginaryCoefficient() {
     return this.coefficient;
  }
```

Now, you can call getImaginaryCoefficient() method and do whatever operation you want to perform.

Something like this,

```
public ComplexNumber add (ComplexNumber a, ComplexNumber b)
 {
    return new ComplexNumber (this.realCoefficient + a.realCoefficient,  a.getImaginaryCoefficient()+b.getImaginaryCoefficient()); //I am confused on what to do here.
 }//More Codes
```